# Rascal-MPL example for C90 code analysis

Tags: rascal

I played with some PICO and Java examples for static analysis in Rascal-MPL, but I found no examples for C (C90). I noticed there is a "lang::c90::\syntax::C", but I found no examples how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no examples yet indeed. In the meantime we are developing a front-end based on the CDT here: https://github.com/cwi-swat/clair

To use the C90 grammar it's a matter of using Rascal's general features, parallel to the PICO examples you explored, but then for C90.

- to parse: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Libraries/Prelude/ParseTree/parse/parse.html
- to match: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Expressions/ConcreteSyntax/ConcreteSyntax.html
- to rewrite: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Expressions/Visit/Visit.html